# Fixing 'Conversion from string to type double is not valid error in VB.NET'

Tags: function, arraylist, datatable, vb.net-2010

When I call the function in the class file, I am getting an error:

> Conversion from string to type double is not valid error in VB.NET

Here is the class file function and also the .aspx page calling function statement:

**Function in the classfile**

```
Public Function readfunctionname(ByVal query As String) As ArrayList
    Try
        connecttodb()
        mysqlcmd = New MySqlCommand(query, con)
        da = New MySqlDataAdapter(mysqlcmd)
        dt = New DataTable
        da.Fill(dt)
        Dim i As Integer = 0
        Do While (i <= (dt.Rows.Count - 1))
            Dim j As Integer = 0
            Do While (j <= (dt.Columns.Count - 1))
                fun_name.Add(dt.Rows(i)(j).ToString)
                j = (j + 1)
            Loop
            i = (i + 1)
        Loop

    Catch ex As Exception
        Throw ex
    Finally
        disconnect()
    End Try
    Return fun_name
End Function
```

**Function call in aspx**

```
For i = 0 To count
    Dim val As Integer = CInt(ddl1.Items(i).Text.ToString)
    nameList = c1.readfunctionname("select fld_funname from tbl_user_function_mast where fld_id='" + val + "'")           
Next
```

I am getting an error like mentioned in the above in the function calling statement in the .aspx proj.

Comment: Aside from anything else, you should use parameterized SQL instead of including the value directly in your SQL statement. You should also tell us *which line* is throwing the exception.

Comment: @jon Skeet this statement am getting error nameList = c1.readfunctionname("select fld_funname from tbl_user_function_mast where fld_id='" + val + "'")

Comment: But presumably *in the method itself*? I wouldn't expect the problem to be creating the arguments.

Comment: @jonSkeet i dont know what's the reason for the error cause

Comment: That's why you should look at the stack trace - and ideally edit it into your question.

Comment: @jonSkeet i dontknow how to edit the question in various way

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the line,

```
fun_name.Add(dt.Rows(i)(j).ToString)
```

to

```
fun_name.Add(dt.Rows(i)(j))
```

I'm not sure which line is causing the error. but I think it's that one.